# Many To Many Creating the relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

There are my 3 classes. Excuse my lack of terminology, I'm a fairly noob at this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my Group Controller, I want to do following in the create method

```
@user = User.first 'Confirmed that this user exists
@group = @user.groups.new(params[:group])

if @group.save
  ... etc
```

The problem that I'm having is that the membership table is blank, I.E if I go to the rails console, and type Membership.all its blanked, but the Group gets generated.

However, if I go to the console and do the following, it will correctly generate a Membership row

```
@user = User.first
@user.groups.create(:name => "name")
Membership.all
```

And the Membership is linked correctly.

Am I doing something wrong in the controller?

Thanks for the help guys/gals!

Comment: does the `@group.save` call return true?

Comment: Yes, @group.save returns true

Comment: What version of rails are you using? I'd like to try to repro this on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .build instead of .new in your controller, like this:

```
@group = @user.groups.build(params[:group])
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work either. It creates the Groups entry but not the Membership

Comment: Try this - Instead of doing `if @group.save`, use `if @user.save`.  Because you're building a new group in the user's context, you need to save the user.  This will in turn save the newly created group.